# Is there a way to show a bootstrap-vue $toast feedback in beforeRouteEnter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I have a component which loads a single user, so I use a `vue-router` guard to load data and in case of error redirect back to the users list component.

Is there a way to show a `vue-bootstrap` `$toast`? Usually I access `$toast` from `this` component, but obviously `this` does not exists yet in `beforeRouteEnter`.

I know I could manage in other ways (show the error in the page and use `created()`, or use `vuex` to keep the error and show it in the next page), but since I am using `$toast` everywhere I would like to keep consistency.

I have no ideas... if only I could access the root component I would have access to `$toast` but I can't see a way.

```js
// userComponent

// ...
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    Promise.all([store.dispatch("users/fetchOne", { id: to.params.id } )])
      .then(next)
      .catch(() => {
        // this.$root.$bvToast.toast("ERROR!!!", { variant: "danger" }); // can't do this :(
        next("/users");
      });
  },
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to this inside beforeRouteEnter. So you can do below :

```
next(vm => {
    vm.$root.$bvToast.toast(...)
})
```